# javascript is adding assets folder to image path (rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have JS code that looks smth like this:

```
...
html_string = '<img src="urlgoeshere" >'
url = "http://www.remote_site.com/address/to/my_pic.png"
html_string.replace(new RegExp("urlgoeshere", 'g'), url)
$('body').append html_string
...
```

So..
It should make this, right?

```
<img src="http://www.remote_site.com/address/to/my_pic.png" >
```

Instead it does this:

```
<img src="/assets/http://www.remote_site.com/address/to/my_pic.png" >
```

Can't do `image_tag`.

How do I get rid of `/assets/` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I think so.

add image_tag to javascript code which is embedded in erb template is making me crazy.  Just use the raw HTML tag is OK.

Comment: but how do I get rid of `/assets/` part?

Comment: found it :) image_tag was inserting it